# Are Fibonacci numbers known to be 'rough' (specifically, not smooth)?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

While commenting on [a question over at MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272803/when-n-some-fibonacci-number), it struck me that Fibonacci numbers tend to not be very smooth; for instance, they can't have GCDs with each other that are too large, they're not generally powers, etc. I'm curious whether anything is known about the smoothness of Fibonacci numbers in a technical sense: specifically, whether it's known that there's an $\epsilon$ such that every sufficiently large $m=F_n$ has a prime divisor $\gt m^\epsilon$, or whether it's known that no such $\epsilon$ can exist.  Some brief searches don't seem to have turned up anything one way or the other, and none of the 'easy' methods of disproof seem to work in this case.  Is there anything known about this specific question one way or the other, or any other sensible notion of 'roughness' for which the question can be definitively answered.

Comment: is it known that there are infinitely many prime Fibonacci numbers? there are some simple results such as if the nth Fibonacci number is prime then n is prime. similar things for more general Lucas sequences.

Comment: @shaihorowitz AFAIK It's not known if there are infinitely many prime Fibonacci numbers any more than it's known if there are infinitely many Mersenne primes. (But of course neither an infinitude of primes or a lack of smooth numbers would imply the other.)

Comment: The largest prime factor of $F_n$ is [OEIS sequence A060385](https://oeis.org/A060385).  It seems only very weak results are known: $A060385(n) \ge n-1$ for $n > 12$.

Comment: According to the b-file for that sequence, some of the Fibonacci numbers are rather smoothish (not a technical term).  Thus $F_{930}$ has  $195$ decimal digits, but its largest prime factor is $5104614261828646351 \approx F_{930}^{0.0964}$.  There may still be an $\epsilon > 0$, but if so it's likely to be rather small.

Comment: @RobertIsrael. Does there exist a non-empty finite set S of primes such that there are infinitely  many n such that all prime divisors of F(n) belong to S?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet In fact, the exact opposite is known: "For all $m\gt 12$, $F_m$ is divisible by some prime which does not divide any $F_k, k\lt m$". See http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/39-5/boase.pdf

Comment: @StevenStadnicki. Thank you for that info & reference.